# Getting value in <select>, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get a current value of SELECT tag. And for this I'm using `$('select').val()`, but this return only default value and it's don't changed. May be I can help me?

```
$('div#buy input').fancybox({
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
        data    : {
            id: $('input[name="id"]').val(),
            count: $('#count').val()
        }
    }
});

<select id="count">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong, because it works: http://jsfiddle.net/aNQJY/

Comment: The problem is that `fancybox` probably runs on page load, so the value is read on page load and then it is of course the default one. You have to read the value when it is changed.

Comment: Mine script is a last loading.

Comment: I think you did not understand what I mean. When do you call `$('div#buy input').fancybox(...)`? Do you call it after the uses selects the value or before that ?

Comment: I've uses select just in .fancybox(), not after

Comment: That is still not what I mean...

Comment: Felix is onto the real issue. There's no problem with `$('#count').val()`. The problem is when you call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, `$('#count').val()` will give the currently selected value for the `<select>` element with id "count". I suspect that your code sample is running before the user has made a selection, and that's why you're getting the default value. You should set your `count` property sometime after the user has made a selection. Something like this will work:

```
var fancyboxOptions = {
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
        data    : {
            id: $('input[name="id"]').val(),
            count: $('#count').val()
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#buy input').fancybox(fancyboxOptions);
    $('#count').change(function() {
        fancyboxOptions.ajax.data.count = $('#count').val();
    });
});
```

This way, the options object will get updated when the selection is changed.

Comment: It's work, but just particual. AJAX sent only count value. Have any ideas about id?

Comment: I'm sure it's having the same problem. You need to add a `change` event handler or some equivalent for it as well.

Comment: Tnx for advice, I'm doing this now ^_^

Answer (score 5):

`$('#count').val()` will return current selected value. you are missing values for option.

```
<select id="count">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>........
```

**Edit :**

If you don't want to specify value in option than you can use.

```
$('#count :selected').val()
```

Comment: You don't need the `value`s. If the attribute is not set, the text is used as value.

Comment: You're right that he can just use $('#count') however it's not because he's missing values for options. Values are optional.

Comment: @Felix Kling, Jamie Dixon . Thanks for clarification.

Comment: `$('#count').val()` already works without any modifications. The problem is that this is executed on page load.

Comment: execute while page load? after this $(document).ready(function() { ? ))

Comment: @NiLL on document.ready you will get default value only.you need to update fancy box on change of select box.

Comment: @Nill on domready selected will be default only . if you want to update your fancy box with selected value than attach a event on change. and than update your fancy box by getting $("count").val()

Answer (score 3):

You can do use the `:selected` selector on dropdowns to get the currently selected item:

```
var selectedValue = $('#count :selected').val()
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a quick fiddle of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/deYmN/

Comment: Your selector is a little off. It should be 'select :selected' (with a space between "select" and ":selected").

Comment: This should not work. `:selected` only works for `option` elements.

Comment: @JamieDixon: Well, before the edit of course ;) `#count:selected` will not work.

Comment: Ah I see your point now Felix. Sorry. You're right. I missed the space initially. Good spot.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('select option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the fancybox/ajax before the user changes the select?

It works fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ERfFA/

Comment: Well when the script loads it picks up the first value (the default).  You have to run the script after a user selects what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('select :selected').val()
```

[Source](http://onerutter.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-tips-how-to-get-value-of-selected-option-in-select-box.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#count option:selected").val();
//Use text to get the text presented on the ui
$("#count option:selected").text();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AKmHU/

Answer (score 1):

The id of your select is "count", so you need do something like this:

$('#count:selected').val()